# How would I use Karabiner elements: to remap the brace key on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I'm used to program in linux whereas left ALT+8 and ALT+9 show { and } (it layout).

Now  I need to press "shift" + "option" + "è" and "shift" + "option" + "+" to have it done.

How can I remap the keyboard in Karabiner Elements so I can use the linux style shortcuts to make braces?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: It's easy to make a custom layout to do this with Ukelele if you are not wedded to Karabiner.  https://software.sil.org/ukelele/

Comment: What's a "linux style brace?"  Wouldn't it just be "brace?" What did you try in Karabiner Elements?  That also seems like a lot of effort for braces...did you change your Input locale to your region?  What is that, by the way?  Finally, there are *tons* of questions/answers on remapping via Karabiner. It's always good to start with a search to see if an answer already exists:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=karabiner+remap

Comment: @Allan  How would changing the "input locale" remap the location of the {} keys on the Italian keyboard layout he wants to use?

Comment: I did not know he was on an Italian keyboard...that’s helpful info.  I asked if he input locale was changed to his region, not to change it to anything.